# Cell height caching and [sizeToFit] on UITableView *sometimes* displays wrong height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

**The Problem**: I'm having an issue where the calculated cell height using estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath returns the wrong height.  Specifically, sometimes the height of a one line text label returns the same height as a sticker (height is way too big).  Or, an image ends up the same height as a single line text label (height is way too small).

**The Theory:** I use different cell heights depending on what type of message it is.  Since sometimes text shows up as an identical height to, say, a sticker (which has a fixed height of 150), I'm wondering if there's a bug somewhere where the cells are being re-used.  Or, there's a bug with the way I'm saving/reading from my cell height cache.

**The Reward:**  I've spent at least a month trying to figure out what's going on.  It's not an easy problem.  You will receive my undying gratitude, as well as a bounty when I can add it.

Here's the code for some context.  First, heightForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {

    NSNumber *cachedCellHeight = [self.cachedCellHeights objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", indexPath.row]];

    if([cachedCellHeight floatValue] >= MINIMUM_CELL_HEIGHT) {
        // NSLog(@"Retrieving cached cell height (estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath): %f for row: %u", [cachedCellHeight floatValue], indexPath.row);
        return [cachedCellHeight floatValue];
    }

    // Cell height is not in the cache (or somehow an invalid height is retrieved), calculate and store it
    NSManagedObject *record = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSInteger type = [[record valueForKey:@"type"] integerValue];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [record valueForKey:@"message"]];

    static NSString *identifier = @"MessagesTableViewCellTextLeft";

    switch (type) {               
        case TypeText:
            identifier = @"MessageTypeText";
            break;

        case TypeImage:
            identifier = @"MessageTypeImage";
            break;

        case TypeSticker:
            identifier = @"MessageTypeSticker";               
            break;
    }

    static MessagesTableViewCell *cell = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: identifier];
    });

    CGFloat calculatedCellHeight;

    UIImage *image = nil;

    switch (type) {
        case TypeText:
            cell.textLabel.text = message;
            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];
            calculatedCellHeight = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height; // used for multi line labels
            break;

        case TypeImage:
            image = [self getImageFromDocumentsFolder:message];

            if (image) {
                calculatedCellHeight = [self getImageCellHeight: image]; // calculates height based on aspect ratio of image
            }

            break;
        case TypeSticker:
            calculatedCellHeight = 150;  // will always be this height
            break;
    }

    /* If the calculation fails and the value is below the minimum cell height, don't store in the cell heights cache */
    if(calculatedCellHeight >= MINIMUM_CELL_HEIGHT) {
        // NSLog(@"Calculating and storing cell height (estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath): %f for row: %u for type: %@", calculatedCellHeight, indexPath.row, identifier);
        [self.cachedCellHeights setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:calculatedCellHeight] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", indexPath.row]];
        [self saveCachedHeightsToDisk];
    } else {
        calculatedCellHeight = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
    }

    return calculatedCellHeight;
}
```

Also, to get multi-line labels to work, I had to set a preferredMaxLayoutWidth in the custom cell class:

```
- (void) updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];

    // For multi-line labels, this property is required to word wrap appropriately
    // In this case, word wrapping will occur 100 units away from screen edge
    textLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = CGRectGetWidth([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]) - 100;
}
```

Here is my implementation of the cell height cache.  Note, cachedCellHeights is just a synthesized NSDictionary:

```
- (void) saveCachedHeightsToDisk {
    NSArray *directoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    if ([directoryPath count] > 0) {
        NSString *rebasedPath = [ClientUtilities rebasePathToCurrentDocumentPath:CACHED_CELL_HEIGHTS_FILENAME];
        [self.cachedCellHeights writeToFile:rebasedPath atomically:YES];
    }
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *) loadCachedHeightsFromDisk {
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *filePath = [ClientUtilities rebasePathToCurrentDocumentPath:CACHED_CELL_HEIGHTS_FILENAME];

    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:filePath]){
        // NSLog(@"Initializing cached cell heights to disk");
        return [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    } else {
        // NSLog(@"Loading cached cell heights from disk");
        return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    }
}
```

Note, the same code is used for both estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath and heightForRowAtIndexPath.  I know you're not supposed to do any heavy calculations in estimatedHeight.  However, since I'm stacking cells from the bottom and they can be wildly varying heights, I have to do this calculation (or read from cache).  Otherwise scroll to bottom functionality doesn't work (it puts the scroll where it thinks the end is based on a bad estimated height calculation, which is some random spot that doesn't make sense).

A solution or any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In iOS 8 and 9, cells can set their own height based on their contents. Is there a good reason you're not taking advantage of this?

Comment: Yep.  Wildly different cell heights.  I *really* wanted to use the standard estimatedHeight/estimatedHeightForRow functionality, but when I did, I got some very jerky scrolling and pretty inaccurate calculations.  My cell heights just vary way too much for me to be able to take advantage of this.  Trust me, I tried.

Tl;dr:  Since I stack my tableview from the bottom, using estimatedCellHeights doesn't work.  When I scroll up, it causes jittery scrolling and looks awful.

Comment: Okay, fair enough; just checking. Well, I've been using variable row heights for years, and my book describes a couple of my standard architectures: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch21.html#_variable_row_heights Perhaps it will help.

Comment: Is the issue that your cache is returning the wrong height or that your calculations are returning the wrong height?

Comment: Good question.  I'd like to know that myself :P

I highly doubt it's the cache.  Once the calculations are done, I store it in the cache.  Then in the future, it's read back out.  The underlying data never changes.  Pretty simple.  I've also done quite a bit of debugging on the cache and it looks solid.

It's more likely that there's some cell reuse thing going on that's causing a cell of a different height to be re-used, thus showing a cell bigger or smaller than intended.

I did put the cache code in here in case someone catches something that I didn't.

Comment: You should remove the caching and see if it still happens to try and narrow down the cause

Comment: Okay, verified that the caching does indeed work.  Ran into this issue again with some logging and it looks like the calculation is incorrect on the cell.  Anyone know if a switch statement can be broken by multi-threading?  I'm thinking this is a concurrency issue given that it only tends to happen under heavy load.  Happens one out of every 30 or 40 cells or so.  Enough to be a nuisance to users.

Comment: Correction.  Caching is indeed broken.  But I don't understand how.  When I look on disk, it shows that there are actually more rows in the plist than actual cells.  Since I set and save the cache in only 1 spot in my code, and if and ONLY if it doesn't exist, how is this even possible?

Comment: So, for example, the plist has 64 entries, but my tableview only has 57 cells.  How.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the cache thing was a red herring.  It's not my cache.  I am sure of it.

I found the offending block that's causing cell height to be way taller than it should:

```
cell.textLabel.text = message;
[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell layoutIfNeeded];
calculatedCellHeight = [cell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize: UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;
NSLog(@"Calculated cell height is: %f", calculatedCellHeight);
```

The height that's being returned by UILayoutFittingCompressedSize is incorrect.  Once it gets in this "state" all text cells evaluate to size 150.  No matter how many times I add a new text cell.  If I force close and come back into the app, it fixes the issue.

I still can't figure out why this is happening.  Threading issue?  Cell reuse issue?  Any suggestions?